# showDialog gives errors in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried WillPopScope, but it's not working at all. Then I tried back_button_interceptor, and it does intercept the backbutton. But the showDialog throws errors. Help please?

```
class LoginState extends State<Login> {
  static String id = "Please scan ID card";
  static String user;
  int sc=0;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();  BackButtonInterceptor.add(myInterceptor);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    BackButtonInterceptor.remove(myInterceptor);
    super.dispose();
  }

  bool myInterceptor(bool stopDefaultButtonEvent) {
    print("BACK BUTTON!"); // Do some stuff.
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      child: new AlertDialog(
        title: new Text('Are you sure?'),
        content: new Text('App will exit'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new FlatButton(
            onPressed: () => true,
            child: new Text('No'),
          ),
          new FlatButton(
            onPressed: () => false,
            child: new Text('Yes'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
    return true;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {---}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make your dialog prevent from closing when tapped outside the area/dialog, add `barrierDismissible: false,` inside your showDialog.

Then you can manually close that dialog with the following example, place this inside actions of your AlertDialog

```
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              child: const Text(
                'Cancel',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: If you're planning to do other stuffs before closing the dialog, change the () => Navigator.of(context).pop() with () => () { // Do stuffs here, then add Navigator.of(context).pop() at the end of this function }

Comment: I'm trying to get the dialog box to show up. I'm just getting a bunch of errors when my Interceptor executes.